# Rails trouble writing integration test for uploading array of files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, minitest

I'm having trouble getting an integration test to pass. A user creates a product, which can have many pictures.  The product's `new.html.erb` contains file field `<%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>` The code works fine, I'm just having problems creating a working integration test.

products_creation_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductsCreationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  .
  .
  .
  test "should create new product with valid info" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    pic1 = fixture_file_upload('test/fixtures/cat1.jpg', 'image/jpg')
    pic2 = fixture_file_upload('test/fixtures/profile.png', 'image/png')
    assert_difference 'Product.count', 1 do
      post user_products_path(@user), product:     { title:       'test',
                                                     description: 'test',
                                                     price:       '5.99', 
                                                     images: [pic1, pic2] } 
    end
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    newprod = @user.products.last
    pics = newprod.pictures.all
    assert_equal 2, pics.count
  end
end
```

This fails the last assertion, stating that there are no pictures associated with the new product, when there should be 2. inspecting the `pics` variable, i get the following error: `RuntimeError: #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []`

What am I missing?

my model structure is as follows:
`User` has_many `Products`, `Products` has_many `Pictures`

products_controller.rb:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :valid_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  .   
  .
  .
  def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(product_params)
    if @product.save
      # to handle multiple images upload on create
      if params[:images]
        params[:images].each { |image|
          @product.pictures.create(image: image)
        }
      end
      flash[:success] = "Product Created!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong."
      render :new
    end
  end
 .
 .
 .
end
```

pictures_controller.rb:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    @picture.save
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def picture_params
       params.require(:picture).permit(:product_id, :image, :_destroy)      
    end
end
```

picture.rb:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  mount_uploader :image, PicturesUploader

  validates_integrity_of  :image
  validates_processing_of :image
  validates :image, file_size: { less_than: 10.megabytes }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved as follows:**

revised products_creation_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductsCreationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  .
  .
  .
  test "should create new product with valid info" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    pic1 = fixture_file_upload('test/fixtures/cat1.jpg', 'image/jpg')
    pic2 = fixture_file_upload('test/fixtures/profile.png', 'image/png')
    assert_difference 'Product.count', 1 do
      post user_products_path(@user), product:     { title:       'test',
                                                     description: 'test',
                                                     price:       '5.99', 
                                                   }, images: [pic1, pic2] 
    end
    assert_redirected_to @user
    newprod = assigns(:product)
    assert_equal 2, newprod.pictures.count
  end
end
```